# An explicit example of a sequence with two special convergent subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for an explicit example of a sequence $(u_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with values in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $(u_{2n})_{n\ge 0}$ and $(u_{3n+1})_{n\ge 0}$ are convergent but $(u_n)$ isn't.

It is easy to see that the sequence $u_n= 0$ if $n=2p$ or $n=3l+1$ and $u_n=1$ else is a good example (since there is infinitely many numbers of the form $6q+5$ (neither even nor of the form $3l+1$)).

But I'm looking here for a more explicit example like $(-1)^n$ in the case $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2n+1})$. I'm looking for a closed formula for $u_n$ (simple as possible).

Comment: What do you mean by "more explicit"?  Is having a closed form all this means?

Comment: Yes. It is what I'm asking at the end of my question.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to make sure that was the full extent to which you meant "more explicit".  The paragraph could be construed as two different things you wanted.

Comment: Could you try something like U_n = (((n)^(nmod(3)-1))^(nmod(2)))? I think you should get 1 on every term k=2n or k=3n+1 but the sequence itself won't converge.

Comment: @JH92 It is not what I will call a closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $2n$ and $3n+1$ have the common sub sequence $6n+4$. Therefore the two sequences must be convergent to the same limit.

It follows that you need $x_{6n},x_{6n+1},x_{6n+2},x_{6n+4}$ to be convergent to the same limit, but one of $x_{6n+3}$ or $x_{6n+5}$ not to be.

This makes a closed form a little hard to find. Anyhow, here is an idea:

Let $\omega$ be a primitive 6th root of unity. The key to the construction is that $\omega^k=-1$ if and only if $k=6n+3$.

Define 
$$y_n=\frac{1}{\omega^n+1+\frac{1}{n}} $$

The issue now is that $x_{6n},x_{6n+1},x_{6n+2},x_{6n+4}$ need to be convergent to the same limit, but

$$\lim_n y_{6n}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lim_n y_{6n+1}=\frac{1}{\omega+1}$$
$$\lim_n y_{6n+2}=\frac{1}{\omega^2+1}$$
$$\lim_n y_{6n+2}=\frac{1}{1-\omega}$$

Pick any nonconstant polynomial $P(X) \in \mathbb C[x]$ such that $P(\frac{1}{2})=P(\frac{1}{\omega+1})=P(\frac{1}{\omega^2+1})=P(\frac{1}{1-\omega})$. For example, let 
$$P(z)=(z-\frac{1}{2})(z-\frac{1}{\omega+1})(z-\frac{1}{\omega^2+1})(z-\frac{1}{1-\omega})$$

Then, if you set 
$$x_n=P(y_n)$$

you have $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n+1}$ converge to $P(\frac{1}{2})=P(\frac{1}{\omega+1})=P(\frac{1}{\omega^2+1})=P(\frac{1}{1-\omega})$, while $x_n$ is not convergent because

$$\lim_{n} x_{6n+3}= \lim_n P(y_{6n+3})= \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

$u_n=n$ if $6\mid n+1$ and $u_n=0$ otherwise.

**addendum**:

$$u_n=\left[1-\lceil6^{-1}\left(n+1\right)-\lfloor6^{-1}\left(n+1\right)\rfloor\rceil\right]n$$

Closed form right :)

Comment: I'm looking for a $u_n$ with a closed form.

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but it's worth a try.